# Force Normal View when generating Word doc via HTML

Tags: asp.net, file, ms-word, export

I am creating an HTML document which we are then pushing out to MS Word using a `application/msword` content type. This works so far except that the files open in Word with Web View. Once Normal View is selected all works fine. Is there any way to force Word to open with Normal View instead of Web View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that works. Save this as `test.htm`, right-click, and open with Word:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
    <head> 
        <title>Test doc</title> 
        <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> 
         <w:WordDocument> 
          <w:View>Normal</w:View> 
          <w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom> 
         </w:WordDocument> 
        </xml><![endif]--> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    To Whom It May Concern, 
    </body> 
</html>
```